# Use Facebook SDK in RubyMotion app

Tags: ios, static-linking, facebook-ios-sdk, rubymotion

I am trying to include the Facebook SDK in my rubymotion app, and I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBSettings.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBNativeDialogs.o)   "_SLServiceTypeFacebook", referenced from:
>         +[FBNativeDialogs composeViewControllerWithSession:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBNativeDialogs.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation) rake aborted! Command failed with status
>   (1): [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer...]

I have tried adding it both through the cocoapod "Facebook-iOS-SKD"

```
 app.pods do 
   pod "Facebook-iOS-SDK"
 end
```

And as a vendor project

```
app.vendor_project('vendor/FacebookSDK.framework', :static, :products => ['FacebookSDK'], :headers_dir => 'Headers')
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get it to link correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the Facebook SDK 3.1 has frameworks that are iOS 6 specific, I had to specify those frameworks as 'weak' in the Rakefile.

```
app.weak_frameworks += %w(AdSupport Social)
```

Credit goes to Laurent Sansonetti for the fix.

Comment: Also, it appears that these frameworks need to be included in the app.frameworks config along with the weak_frameworks.